# I am getting an error when i run setup : Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, error, setup

I am getting below error:

> Call to a member function getDefaultStore() on boolean in
>   D:\wampstack\apache2\htdocs\juliasvn\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php
>   on line 562

can anyone have any idea about the error?

Comment: what steps have you taken ?

Comment: you install magneto1 or magento2?

Comment: what version of php are you running on WAMP?